# How to add a char* inside of a char*?

Tags: c++

How do I add, for example, message, inside of this char*?

```cpp
add_message(char* message) {
   char* json = "{\"message\": \"%%insert message here%%\"}"
}
```

I'm really new to C++ and don't know any terms, so forgive me if this is too simple.

Comment: In C++ you should use `std::string` to manipulate character strings instead of pointers. Those can be concatenated with a simple `+` operator.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: In this particular case, if C++20 is available, [`std::format` is probably the way to go](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format). Pre-C++20, yeah, `+` or `std::stringstream`, depending on complexity.

Comment: If you want to concatenate C-style strings (char arrays), then you probably need to use the function [`std::strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat). However, when using that function, you must ensure that the memory buffer holding the string is large enough to hold the concatenated string (both strings and the terminating null character). If you don't want to have to worry about this, then you can simply use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead.

Comment: Even more important: When composing JSON **use a JSON serialization library**. If you don't you'll end up with all kinds of encoding issues, quoting problems, or worse.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks, I'll start using std::string. It's just that I saw everyone doing char*, so I did that.

Comment: @tadman I'm going to send just one request, and I don't think I'll need full on JSON seralizers.

Comment: @MatteoLeullier: The people you are referring to as "everyone" were probably C programmers, not C++ programmers. :)

Comment: @MatteoLeullier That's the sort of thing people end up having chiselled into their tombstones, figuratively speaking. Do it properly and you won't get burned. You're one `"This \"message\" is great!"` away from failure here, or if there's a newline in that content, or...

Comment: Use [libfmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) - https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Mqqavh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to concatenate the wisdom presented in the comments, and to ease the transition of the new C++ programmer, here is a tiny (and silly) sample code,

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

std::string add_message(const std::string& body) {
    std::string json = "{\"message\": \"%%" + body + "%%\"}";

    return json;
}

int main()
{
    std::string body = "This is a message body"; 

    std::cout << "For the body '" << body 
              << "' the JSON msg is '" << add_message(body) << "'" 
              << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `add_message` should probably have an argument of type`string_view` or `const string&`

Comment: `add_message()` could even be simplified to just `return "{\"message\": \"%%" + body + "%%\"}";` since `body` is already `std::string`.

Comment: Dear @scohe001, that is obvious, but just one line more can make the code a little clearer.

Comment: You're rigt, @AyxanHaqverdili. Edited the code to reflect your comment.